# Debian Software raid not getting synced

Tags: debian, raid

my Software-Raid under Debian suddenly says:

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0](F) sdb3[1]
2917156159 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
12581816 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

But a complete 6 hour check did result in a fully functional hard drive. So the HDD is OK.

So I did the following:

```
mdadm /dev/md2 --remove /dev/sda3
mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sda3
```

This I think worked until 50% but now the RAID says:

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0](S) sdb3[1]
2917156159 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
12581816 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

What the hell is going wrong?

Edit: Okey the fdisk -l shows the following (the disks are two identically HDDs):

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      266306  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      266306  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/md0: 12.9 GB, 12883779584 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 3145454 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 536 MB, 536858624 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 131069 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 2987.2 GB, 2987167906816 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 729289039 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Edit 2:

```
root@ICELAND ~ # gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.1

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 602051E0-41A7-4BD3-BEBD-0072BF1940A3
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1            4096        25169919   12.0 GiB    FD00  
2        25169920        26218495   512.0 MiB   FD00  
3        26218496      5860533134   2.7 TiB     FD00  
4            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  EF02  
root@ICELAND ~ # gdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.1

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 1845979C-A245-48E6-88F7-163163A39A6B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1            4096        25169919   12.0 GiB    FD00  
2        25169920        26218495   512.0 MiB   FD00  
3        26218496      5860533134   2.7 TiB     FD00  
4            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  EF02  
root@ICELAND ~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Tue Oct 23 19:11:10 2012
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 2917156159 (2782.02 GiB 2987.17 GB)
Used Dev Size : 2917156159 (2782.02 GiB 2987.17 GB)
Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Wed Sep 11 19:12:03 2013
State : active, degraded
Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 1

       Name : rescue:2
       UUID : d09a5141:6abfc440:358a06e7:9445fbea
     Events : 2256201

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3

   0       8        3        -      spare   /dev/sda3
root@ICELAND ~ #
```

Comment: Welcome to the serverfault. Please always provide as much information as possible: logs, version strings, partition size, how disk was added, are they same, output of `fdisk -l` etc

Comment: I updated my post, which log file would you like to see?

Comment: `gdisk -l /dev/sda` + `gdisk -l /dev/sdb` + `mdadm --detail /dev/md2`

Comment: I want to see the `dmesg` output after you try re-adding that drive.  I also want to know i fyou have checked the SMART output for that drive, to be sure it isn't actually failing.

Comment: I re-edited again. The SMART check has not been made by myself. It was checked by the support of the datacenter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3

   0       8        3        -      spare   /dev/sda3
```

Spare is not activated. Usually this happens when device is failing.

Try following:

```
mdadm /dev/md2 -r /dev/sda3
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda3
mdadm /dev/md2 -a /dev/sda3
```

and then check `cat /proc/mdstat`.

If it will fail - check your hard drive and cables, `dmesg`, syslog and smart data.

Comment: Ok I have done this... and again it is SPARE. I have this in the syslog: http://pastebin.com/1TB6V5q0 And this in the dmesg: http://pastebin.com/12Y8t0um

Comment: Looks like your device is failing.

Comment: So I will call the datacenter right?

Comment: Yes, show them this log: http://pastebin.com/1TB6V5q0

Comment: The Datacenter support needs the SerialNo of the failed device. Can you confirm that this is the correct SerialNO: 
_# udevadm info --query=property --name=sda | grep ID_SERIAL_
  **ID_SERIAL=ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F0VSQB**

Comment: ST3000DM001-9YN166 is model, W1F0VSQB is S/N

Comment: Okey and device sda is the failed device... Thank you very much, I don't want to change the one and only working hdd

Comment: No, sdb is failed - mdraid cannot read data from it and therefore it cannot sync, you must backup your data and reinstall the system. Read log carefully.

Comment: Oh wait a second, the device can not read... Is it propably because there are openvz virtual machines running or something like that?

Comment: No, this is hardware/media problem. You can try to disable NCQ, but in normal situation it must work anyway: `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/queue_depth` you must check drive.